# How to remove the error Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, formview

I have a table which has a username field with datatype `uniqueidentifier`. I'm simply trying to insert the `userid` from a FormView like this in the `SqlDataSource` inserting event

```
e.Command.Parameters["@U_Name"].Value = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey);
```

The insert query of the data source looks like this

```
INSERT INTO [tblSwitch] ([SWITCH_NAME], [BIT_NUM], [IsOn], [USER_ID]) 
VALUES (@SWITCH_NAME, @BIT_NUM, @IsOn, @USER_ID)
```

but it throws an error

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Kindly guide me

Comment: 1) Since `@U_Name` doesn't exist in your SQL, this is obviously not the actual code that's running, and 2) That error message seems to indicate that SQL is having to perform the conversion. Given that you've already converted it to a `Guid` in C#, this would tend to indicate that you've got the wrong data type for your parameter and are actually doing string -> Guid -> string -> Guid conversions. But you've not shown the parameter definitions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever after removing Guid conversion Now i got this error Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to remove the Guid conversion - I was suggesting you locate the bit where, having already converted it to a guid, **something** is converting it **back** into a *string*. If you can locate that problem and remove it, all should be good.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks done after removing Type = "Object" of the parameter